# sql alcehmy orm models combining multiple models into one model

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, single-table-inheritance

I have a table with huge number of columns say 100.
This single table with name say `records` stores multiple types of records, kinda single table inheritance. I want to design SQL-Alchemy modles like this.

```
Class BaseRecord(db.Model):
  ## common attributes their getter and setter here

Class RecordOne(BaseRecord):
  ## specific attributes and their getter and setter here

Class RecordTwo(BaseRecord):
 ## specific attributes and their getter and setter here

Class Record(RecordOne, RecordTwo):
 ## functions to query records table here
```

Problem here is that ORM mapper only maps RecordOne class attributes to Record. I can not insert anything related to RecordTwo using Record class.
I want the freedom that if i know type of record i can insert using RecordOne or RecordTwo or if i don't know the type i should be able to insert using Record